# Condition for $k$ dimensional manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

From Spivak's book chapter 5. A subset $M\subset \Bbb{R^n}$ is called a k-dimensional manifold if for every point $x\in M$ the following condition is satisfied : There is an open set $U$ containing $x$ and an open set $V\subset \Bbb{R^n}$ and a diffeomorphism $h : U \to V $ such that $$h(U\cap M)=V\cap(\Bbb{R^k}\times{0})=\{y\in V:y^{k+1}=\cdots y^n=0\}.$$

"In other words $U\cap M$ is "up to diffeomorphism" simply $\Bbb{R^k}\times {0}.$ From the figures in the book, it would seem $h(x)$ is always centered at the origin of the image $h(U\cap M).$ What confuses me most, is the term $\Bbb{R^k} \times \{0\}$. These are $k+1$ dimensional points. Does this definition by itself mean, that $h(U\cap M)$ is some sort of a plane where $h(x)$ lies in the origin? Because this would seem to be the case from given figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Spivak's statement that *$U\cap M$ is "up to diffeomorphism" simply $\Bbb{R^k}\times \{0\}$* is a bit too sloppy. At best $U\cap M$ is up to diffeomorphism an *open subset of $\Bbb{R^k}\times \{0\}$*, but even that formulation is misleading because it suggests that we have a concept for a map $U \cap M \to V \cap (\Bbb{R^k}\times \{0\})$ to be a diffeomorphism.

One can define such a concept, but in Spivak's sense a diffeomorphism is a certain  map between open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ - and nothing else. What is meant is that $M$ can be "flattened" locally via diffeomorphisms on open subsets of the ambient $\mathbb R^n$. In fact, $\Bbb{R^k}\times \{0\}$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and thus a special *$k$-plane in $\mathbb R^n$* (note that arbitrary $k$-planes need not contain the origin). It is also important to observe that $h : U \cap M \to V \cap  (\Bbb{R^k}\times \{0\})$ is a *homeomorphism*, and since $\Bbb{R^k}\times \{0\}$ is canonically homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$ we see that $U \cap M$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^k$. This means that *topologically $M$ looks locally like  $\mathbb R^k$.*

The idea for calling $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ a *$k$-manifold* is that $M$ looks locally like  $\mathbb R^k$ and additionally must be "smooth" without corners, edges etc. For example the subset $M  = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x= 0 , y \ge 0 \text{ or } y = 0, x \ge 0\}$ is homeomorphic to the real line $\mathbb R$, but it has a corner at the origin: No diffeomorphisms $h : U \to V$ on an open neigborhood $U$ of $0$ can have the property that $h(U \cap M) \subset \mathbb R \times \{0\}$.

The above considerations show that a manifold $M$ can be described locally by a curvilinear smooth coordinate system $\xi_1,\ldots, \xi_n$ such that for $ \xi = (\xi_1,\ldots, \xi_n)$ we have  $ \xi \in M$ iff $\xi_i = 0$ for $i > k$. Examples for curvilinear smooth coordinate systems are polar coordinates in the plane and spherical coordinates for three-dimensional space.

In Spivaks' figures we have in fact $h(x) = 0$. However, this is not required in the definition, $h(x)$ can be any point of $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$. Nevertheless *we may assume w.l.o.g.* that $h(x) = 0$: The translations $t_a : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n, t_a(\xi) = \xi + a$, are diffemorphisms, and if we start with $h : U \to V$, then the diffeomorphism $\tilde h : U \stackrel{h}{\to} V  \stackrel{T_{-h(x)}}{\to} T_{-h(x)}(V) = \tilde V$ has the desired property.